# Access SQL Server Database on ASP.Net website from Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, xamarin.ios

I want to access my database on my ASP.Net website in my Xamarin.iOS app. I want to know how I can work with SQL commands to access my procedures, insert, update, or delete values. I also want to return values from my database and show them in my app. How is this possible? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You actually don't want to do that. Expose the operations you need as an API from your web site.

Comment: @Crowcoder Do you have any complete tutorials for that? Or a keyword that I can search on Internet for that?

Comment: Such a service is often called a Web API. Maybe search "mobile backend". Any information on services for "single page apps" would be relevant too.

Comment: @Crowcoder Uh-huh! So my website should be MVC too. Thanks for your answer. 